# NextJs: Hide Header and Footer only in SignIn / Register pages?

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js

I've rendered Header and footer on all of my pages, But for couple of my pages I don't want them. This is my Layout.js. Thanks.

*

```
import React from "react";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Notify from "./Notify";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import Footer from "./Footer";
function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Notify />
      <Modal />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Layout;
```

- 

And _app.js

*

```
*import "../styles/globals.scss";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { DataProvider } from "../store/GlobalState";
import Head from "next/head";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;*
```

- 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can take another `authPage` prop to `Layout` component. Initiate it with a default `false` value.

```js
function Layout({ children, authPage = false }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {!authPage && <NavBar />}
      <Notify />
      <Modal />
      {children}
      {!authPage && <Footer />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then in the Sign/Register page you can render it like this:

```js
<Layout authPage = {true}>
  ....
</Layout>
```

For all other pages:

```js
<Layout>
  ....
</Layout>
```

You can check the implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-layout-template-001?embed=1&file=pages/index.js)

Comment: Dear Rakib, This works fine. Yet I have to route every single page with additional Layout prop. Is there a way to fake it just for the pages which I want not to render the components?

Comment: Thanks @SanjayaSenarathane We need to pass the additional prop only for Sign/Register page, other pages don't need this prop as we initiate with a default false value. I have edited the answer a bit, please check.

Comment: Dear Rakib, Now I'm getting double of each :)) I mean two of each Footers and Headers. Still can't figure this out.

Comment: I guess you used `Layout` both in `_app.js` and all pages, but we don't need `Layout` at _app.js You can check an implementation [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-layout-template-001?devtoolsheight=33&file=pages/index.js)
Please open the project using Chrome.

Comment: Rakib , actually I followed this tutorial for my project.  https://youtu.be/gkogXBSElPw?list=PLs4co9a6NhMzf-5tIWfpzDCgdMyg-CceX&t=271

Answer (score 2):

```
function Layout({ children, isLogin }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {isLogin && <NavBar />}
      <Notify />
      <Modal />
      {children}
      {isLogin && <Footer />}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Layout;
```

What this does is if isLogin is true it will return the Navbar and Footer component and it will return null if isLogin is false.

Just replace isLogin with whatever variable your using to identify if the user is logged in or not...

Comment: Ok, that's not the feature I'm looking for. I needed to render a page outside the layout.