# How to hide the Footer component at a specific URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/aboutlayout-o3gmd?file=/src/App.js

In the `Header` are `Routes`, when you go to `/cabinet` render component `<Cabinet/>`, I need to make it so that when you are on the route `/cabinet` component `<Footer />` should not be rendered

Tried to get the current path using hook `const match = useRouteMatch()`, but it must be called inside the component `<Cabinet/>`, but the path I need in the component `<App/>`, to make a condition, `{match !== /cabinet && <Footer />}` how do I get the current path is in the `<App/>` component?

I also wanted to use `const match = useRef(window.location.pathname);` but it doesn't update

`<App/> component` :

```
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Catalog } from "./pages/Catalog";
import { Cabinet } from "./pages/Cabinet";
import { Header } from "./components/Header";
import { Footer } from "./components/Footer";
import { Page404 } from "./pages/Page404";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const match = useRef(window.location.pathname);
  // const [path, setPath] = useState(window.location.pathname)

  console.log(match);
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/"} exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/catalog"} exact>
            <Catalog />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/cabinet"} exact>
            <Cabinet />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"*"}>
            <Page404 />
          </Route>
          {/* <Redirect to={'/'} /> */}
        </Switch>
        <Footer />

        {/*
        {true && <Footer />}  // will be rendered
        {false && <Footer />} // will not be rendered
        {(match !== /cabinet) && <Footer />} 
        */}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export { App };
```

Comment: try like that  {(match !== '/cabinet') && <Footer />}

Comment: Yes, but for the `match`  to change, I need to reload the page, it does not change when you change the ` route` try this on codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/aboutlayout-o3gmd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Bob I guess you can make use of Layout component in this situation. I faced kind of same issue like this in a Next.js project and solved it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69751870/5041988).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useLocation()` hook to check the route path in the `<Footer />` component.

**Example :**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Footer = ({ path }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  console.log(pathname);
  if (pathname === "/cabinet") return null;

  return <div className="footer">Footer</div>;
};
export { Footer };
```

**App.js**

```
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { Catalog } from "./pages/Catalog";
import { Cabinet } from "./pages/Cabinet";
import { Header } from "./components/Header";
import { Footer } from "./components/Footer";
import { Page404 } from "./pages/Page404";

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path={"/"} exact>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/catalog"} exact>
            <Catalog />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"/cabinet"} exact>
            <Cabinet />
          </Route>
          <Route path={"*"}>
            <Page404 />
          </Route>
          {/* <Redirect to={'/'} /> */}
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
};

export { App };
```